# How addEventListener Handling?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a simple form like this:

```
<form name="testform">
<input name="inputin" type="text">
<button name="sbtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and some Javascript code to get input on submit:

```
var form = document.forms.testform;
var user = {};
user.name = form.inputin.value;

function output(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(user.name);
}
form.addEventListener('submit', output, false);
```

The problem is the code above doesn't work but when i define user and user.name inside function output() like this:

```
function output(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var user = {};
    user.name = form.inputin.value;
    alert(user.name);
}
```

It does work. I'm self-learning Javascript and don't understand why. :(

Comment: It's because the code inside the event handler runs when the form is submitted, when there's actual input to capture. The code outside the event handler runs on pageload only, when the input has no value to capture.

Comment: @adeneo: Ah, yes, and there's that. (Doh)

Comment: @adeneo You mean event handler doesn't handle outside of the output() function? Then I should only define any related variables to the event inside the function. Thank you!

Comment: @Jane, yes exactly! The variables of the output function need to be defined within the function in your case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Havent tested it but you could try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var user = {};

        $("form[name=testform]").submit(function(e)){
           user.name = $("input[name=inputin]").val();
             if(user.name){
                     e.preventDefault();
                     alert(user.name);

             }
         });
});
```

Comment: This works but i just try to understand what is wrong with my code and how Event Handling. Thank you!

Comment: the HTML file (including your script) is executed sequentially when the page is loading. At that time, your variables, such as , `user.name = form.inputin.value;` have no value, and therefore your `output` function will not show anything. 

When you put your variables in the function and call the function in the submit, then the variable are being defined and your object is getting populated, that's why you get the values.

Comment: Yeah you're right. The problem is with the DOM, i mean identifiers of Javascript not because of event handler. Changed user.name = form.inputin; and alert(user.name.value); then it does work! Thank you @callback

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess the first few lines

```
var form = document.forms.testform,
var user = {};
user.name = form.inputin.value;
```

Seem wrong to me, change the comma (,) to a semi colon (;) so it reads like this:

```
var form = document.forms.testform;
var user = {};
user.name = form.inputin.value;
```

You can multi-line declare variables but not like this, you can omit the 'var' declaration on all subsequent variables. Best for now to just do a full declaration each time.

Comment: While all that's true, I suspect [adeneo's point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144999/how-addeventlistener-handling#comment46512675_29144999) is more germane.